# Pagination is not working in archive page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Every pagination link take me to the first page every time. I have tried with or without a plugin, but nothing works. It doesn't matter if I click on the *Next* button or the *Prev* button. It always takes me to the first page.

```
<?php
    /*
        Template Name: Notices & Circulars
    */
    get_header(); ?>

    <div class="banner-box">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="main-top">
                <div class="main">
                    <h1><div class="titlepage"><?php the_title();?></div></h1>
                    <section class="content">
                    <?php
                        $args=array(
                            'cat'=> 14,
                            'posts_per_page' => 10,
                            'offset' => 5,
                            'paged' => get_query_var('page')
                        );
                        if ( have_posts() ) :
                            query_posts($args);
                    ?>

                            <?php while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
                                <li style="list-style:none;">
                                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?  >"><font style="color:#666666;"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <?php
                                     /***** Thumbnail ******/
                                     the_post_thumbnail(
                                         array(120, 90),
                                         array(
                                             'class' => 'thumbnail',
                                             'alt' => 'post thumbnail',
                                             'title' => 'my custom title'
                                         )
                                     );
                                     /******* Thumbnail Ends ********/

                                     the_content(__('Continue Reading'));?></font>
                                </li><hr /><?php
                            endwhile;

                            wp_pagenavi();
                        endif;
                        ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php get_footer(); ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML (after the PHP processing). The two HTML tags `h3` and `font` are overlapping (near "color:#666666").

Comment: Yes, coz there is space bw closing php tag (?>) after "the_title()" function inside anchor tag. Since it is old post, I don't remember if this space was issue or something else. Anyway thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<?php
  /*
   Template Name: Notices & Circulars
 */
 get_header(); ?>
   <div class="banner-box">
  <div class="wrap"><div class="main-top"><div class="main">
  <h1><div class="titlepage"><?php the_title();?></div></h1>
  <section class="content">
<?php 
// Example for adding WP PageNavi to a new WP_Query call
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'post','cat'=> 14,'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
     <li style="list-style:none;">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><font style="color:#666666;"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php 
  /*****     Thumbnail     ******/
  the_post_thumbnail(
  array(120, 90), 
    array(

    'class' => 'thumbnail',
    'alt' => 'post thumbnail',
    'title' => 'my custom title'
 )
 );
 /*******     Thumbnail Ends   ********/
 the_content(__('Continue Reading'));?></font>          
    </li><hr />
    <?php 
endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) ); ?>
</div></div></div>
<?php get_footer();?></div>
```

Comment: It worked! But i have one question, Why `offset` is removed. I tried to put it back in your code then my pagination stopped working But when I again remove `offset` then its start working again! Why `offset is causing trouble?

Comment: offset is nothing more than a parameter that tells WordPress where to begin pulling posts. If you’re on the first page, the offset should be zero.
If you’re on page two, then it should be however many posts you’ve already displayed (less one, since we start counting at zero) multiplied by the page that you’re on.

Still, If you want to use offset then you can use this kind of code:
$display_count = 10;
$offset = ( $page - 1 ) * $display_count;
$args = array('post_type' => 'post','cat'=> 4,'posts_per_page' => 10, 'offset' => $offset,'paged' => $paged);

Comment: Thanks Mohod Sandhya! I really appreciate your knowledge :-)

Comment: Can you add a few words about what you changed (by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36150975/edit))? Thanks in advance.